# Rails API on heroku using huge memory for simple task (render Model.all as JSON)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a basic API on heroku. It should render an entire table (7.2MB) of data.

Instead, I get a R14 error (Memory quota exceeded). The details say that the app is using 724MB! I don't know how this is possible for such a basic application, when I am the only one using it.

Here's the controller

```rb
  def index
    @flatfiles = Flatfile.all
    render json: @flatfiles
  end
```

And the route

```
  get 'flatfiles/:key' => 'flatfiles#index'
```

I have tried `heroku restart` but that was unfruitful.

The `Flatfile` table is ~270k rows and two columns (around 20 characters per value in each column). The size of the data in csv is 7.2MB. I would not have expected this to be any problem for a dyno with 0.5GB memory available.

Comment: You probably don't need all columns in Flatfile, and probably don't need all rows at once. Try implementing pagination for that.

Comment: Bear in mind that the memory usage you see on Heroku is for your entire application, including your web server. It can often be higher than you might expect if you're new to the platform.

Comment: It turned out by excluding unnecessary columns (`created_at` and `updated_at`), it works fine now (they probably doubled the size of the data, pushing it over its limit).

Comment: Render all will make Rails load all these data to memory. Consider using some pagination tools to request by page. If you really need all data return in one request. Consider save them to cache db like redis. And flush cache when data changed